# In Drupal 6, is there a way to take a custom field from the latest post to a taxonomy term, and display it in a view?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

The title for this question pretty much sums up what I'm asking.

I've got a list of taxonomy terms, and I'm using a view to display the latest post to each one. I'd like to also display a custom field set up in CCK just under this.

Currently, I'm just using "date updated" of the taxonomy term itself which was easy to set up in views. I'd like to drill a little deeper and get the custom "event date" field I've added to the content type last posted to the taxonomy term I'm "viewing".

I've got a feeling I'm going to have to write my own database query for this.

If (I can avoid that){
How do I set up such a view?
}
Else{
What's the best practice for including lower level database queries alongside views?
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using row style instead of node style for your view, and building the desired look of the view with a custom module? this would let you send the fields you want to the page and then theme them however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

See this issue on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/193187. Technically, SQL does not allow you do a grouped query and set a limit per group. It would be possible to execute a grouped query and only display the first of each group on the theme level. However, depending on the number of nodes, that might not perform too well - I'm not sure.